# Conditions for PSTricks figure

Tags: pstricks

I have tried to create a PSTricks figure based on only a few parameters but I have a problem.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN
    \calc
  \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Parameters
\def\radius{1.5 }
\def\doublelayers{2}
\def\columns{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\def\diameter{\calc{2*\radius}}
\def\distance{\calc{2*3^(1/2)*\radius}}
\def\width{\calc{(2*\columns+1)*\radius}}
\def\height{\calc{(2+3^(1/2)*(\doublelayers-1))*\radius}}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\width,\height)
   \rput(\radius,\radius){
     \multido{\rC=0+\diameter}{\columns}{
       \multido{\rD=0+\distance}{\doublelayers}{
         \psdot(\rC,\rD)
         \pscircle(\rC,\rD){\radius}
       }
     }
   }
   \rput(!2 \radius mul 1 3 sqrt add \radius mul){
     \multido{\rE=0+\diameter}{\columns}{
       \multido{\rF=0+\distance}{\doublelayers}{
         \psdot(\rE,\rF)
         \pscircle(\rE,\rF){\radius}
       }
     }
   }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The document should be compiled using

```
pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>.tex
```

**Question**

How do I change the code from using `\doublelayers` to using *single* layers? The point is that if there are 2n layers, there should be should be drawn n layers to the far-left and n layers indented by an amount of `\radius`; if there are 2n-1 layers, there should be should be drawn n layers to the left and n-1 layers indented.

*Example*: If I have three layers, the code should draw two rows of circles beginning at the left of the figure and one row of circles in between, indented.

The following picture shows 2 double layers. With 3 single layers, the top row shouldn't be there.

[image]

**Update**

I have crosspost this to the [LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22710) since this post seems to be `dead', so I try there.

Comment: I've posted one possible solution.  I'm a bit unclear why this was difficult for you.  I suspect that I am probably not understanding what you're really asking for.  I think you'll get more bites if you post your own attempt (even if it doesn't work), at accomplishing what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really foggy on what you're asking for.

Is this what you're asking for?

[image]

If the above image is the case, there's a very easy solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN
    \calc
  \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Parameters
\def\radius{1.5 }
\def\doublelayers{3}
\def\columns{2}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\def\diameter{\calc{2*\radius}}
\def\distance{\calc{2*\radius}}%{\calc{2*3^(1/2)*\radius}}
\def\width{\calc{(2*\columns+1)*\radius}}
\def\height{\calc{(2+3^(1/2)*(\doublelayers-1))*\radius}}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\width,\height)
   \rput(\radius,\radius){
     \multido{\rC=0+\diameter}{\columns}{
       \multido{\rD=0+\distance}{\doublelayers}{
         \psdot(\rC,\rD)
         \pscircle(\rC,\rD){\radius}
       }
     }
   }
%   \rput(!2 \radius mul 1 3 sqrt add \radius mul){
%     \multido{\rE=0+\diameter}{\columns}{
%       \multido{\rF=0+\distance}{\doublelayers}{
%         \psdot(\rE,\rF)
%         \pscircle(\rE,\rF){\radius}
%       }
%     }
%   }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Are you asking for something more or less dynamic, so that you can specify how ever many layers you want?

OK.  I think I understand a bit better what you want.  Here's a MWE.  It could use some improving, but I'm tired right now.  I'll come back to it tomorrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN
    \calc
  \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Parameters
\def\radius{0.75 }
\def\doublelayers{5}
\newcounter{bluedoublelayers}
\ifodd\doublelayers\relax%
    \setcounter{bluedoublelayers}{\number\numexpr\doublelayers-1\relax}%
    \else%
    \setcounter{bluedoublelayers}{\doublelayers}%
    \fi
\def\columns{2}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\def\diameter{\calc{2*\radius}}
\def\distance{\calc{2*3^(1/2)*\radius}}
\def\width{\calc{(2*\columns+1)*\radius}}
\def\height{\calc{(2+3^(1/2)*(\doublelayers-1))*\radius}}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\width,\height)
   \rput(\radius,\radius){
     \multido{\rC=0+\diameter}{\columns}{
       \multido{\rD=0+\distance}{\doublelayers}{
         \psdot(\rC,\rD)
         \pscircle(\rC,\rD){\radius}
       }
     }
   }
   \rput(!2 \radius mul 1 3 sqrt add \radius mul){
     \psset{linecolor=blue}
     \multido{\rE=0+\diameter}{\columns}{
       \multido{\rF=0+\distance}{\thebluedoublelayers}{
                \psdot(\rE,\rF)
                \pscircle(\rE,\rF){\radius}
       }
     }
   }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When you set `doublelayers` to `2`, the result is:

[image]

When you set `doublelayers` to `3`, the result is:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking for. :) I am not used to begin abel to attach pictures but I have done that now.

Comment: This looks promising, @a.ellett! I would like to create single layers instead of doubles so that I can draw, say, three columns and three rows by setting `\def\rows{3}` (there `\doublelayers` is replaced by `\rows`) and `\def\columns{3}`.

Comment: Have you (or anyone else) come up with an idea of how to do what I would like to accomplish?